# не откликается камера на планшете

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь подключится к камере планшета и сделать снимок.

```js
(function() {
    var video = document.getElementById('video'),
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        photo = document.getElementById('photo'),
        vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.
        mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    navigator.getMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: false
    }, function(stream) {
        video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    }, function(error) {
        alert('Ошибка! Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте позже.');
    });
    document.getElementById('capture').addEventListener('click', function() {
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 400, 300);
        photo.setAttribute('src', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    });
})();
```

```css
.booth {
    width: 400px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 10px solid #ddd;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.booth-capture-button {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: cornflowerblue;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#canvas {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Приложение</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="booth">
    <video id="video" width="400" height="300" autoplay></video>
    <a href="#" id="capture" class="booth-capture-button">Сфотографировать</a>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
    <img id="photo" alt="Ваша фотография">
</div>
<script src="camera.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

При запуске браузера даю разрешение на использование камеры, но больше ничего не происходит, камера не активируется, точнее камера загорается лампочка и далее ничего и по нажатию на кнопку ничего не происходит. Браузер Chrom последняя версия. Не пойму в чем ошибка.

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что стрим не воспоизводится? Или стрим воспроизводится, но не работает кнопка "Сфотографировать"? Проблема только на одном конкретном планшете или на других устройствах (телефон, ноутбук) тоже не работает?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин на планшете лампочка возле камеры загорается, но стрим не воспроизводится. На ноуте вообще никаких реакций. На ноуте и планшете стоит 10 винда, если это имеет какое-то значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая штука [дебаг-панель](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open). При отладке скрипта в неё полезно поглядывать. Вот что там появляется при запуске вашего кода: `TypeError: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 1-argument overloads of URL.createObjectURL`. Метод не хочет делать objectUrl из стрима.

Но! Если у видео есть свойство `srcObject`, то в него можно просетить стрим, не создавая url: `video.srcObject = stream;`. Это будет работать в современных браузерах (в вашем хроме в том числе).

Пример использования getUserMedia в старых браузерах есть в [статье на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia). Кроме того там отличная документация с [примерами](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos).

Comment: в дебаге вылетает ошибка: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectUrl' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided at camera.js:13`

Comment: видимо нужно не создавать url как вы и написали?

Comment: `video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);` замените на `video.srcObject = stream;` как я и написал. И почитайте документацию на MDN, там действительно круто всё расписано.